# Javascript if conditional variable problem

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have two receiver type. 0 for guests 1 for users. I'm trying to push notification from firebase cloud functions. I can send notification user to guest succesfully. But can not send notification guest to user. Is there any problem with my if condition?

```
    var usersRef = null;
    if (receiverType === 0) { 
        usersRef = admin.firestore().collection('Guests').doc(receiverId);
    } else {
        usersRef = admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(receiverId);
    }
```

I want to change var usersRef variable based on receiverType. I managed to change it to Guest path but on the else part its path must change again to Users. But not changing. There is a problem in my if else statement.

```
    var getDoc = usersRef.get()
        .then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                return null;
            } else {
                const token = doc.data().token;

                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: "New Message",
                        body: chatMessage,
                    }
                };

                admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
                    .then((response) => {
                        // Response is a message ID string.
                        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
                        return null;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
                        return null;
                    });

            }
            return null;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting document', err);
            return null;
        });
    return null;
});
```

Comment: I only see one Cloud Function in the code you shared. Can you explicitly give the name of the function that is not working?

Comment: I also highly recommend limiting the scope of your question. If you function doesn't get triggered, that is unrelated to the code that is in it. This means you should be able to get the same behavior/problem with just a `console.log('does not get executed')` as the function body, which removes Firebase Cloud Messaging from the equation. This means we have less code to consider, which makes it more likely someone will spot the problem. For more on this, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Puf. I edited my question.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding the problem. What line in your code doesn't do what you expect it to do?